# want to understand whatsapp work flow and architecture

Tags: whatsapp

I have some questions like how whatsapp server is working, though I read in internet, I want to understand much. And what is XMPP? how it is working, How can I send data through XMPP. how can I integrate XMPP with application, can anyone pls explain?

Comment: I am not sure this question fully qualifies as valid, it is a bit vague. I'll try however to provide and answer, see below.

Answer (score 0):

**WhatsApp under the hood?**

There are rumors WhatsApp uses a customized version of XMPP. Sources are closed so we can only guess.

Understanding XMPP will however give you all the tools to create your own WhatsApp clone.

**What is XMPP?**

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP) (which hosts further references):

> Extensible Messaging and Presence Protocol (XMPP) is a communications protocol for message-oriented middleware based on XML (Extensible Markup Language).

Which is to say that **XMPP** is an xml based convention for exchanging messages between parties. It's best known implementation is [Ejabberd](https://www.ejabberd.im/) chat server.
XMPP can however be used for other things, among them **the web of things**.

**How to send messages?**

Assuming you want to create a chat application, you will need:

- An Ejjaberd server up and running.
- An appropriate xmpp SDK for you language/framework. Example: ***Smack*** for ***Java*** or ***agsXMPP*** for ***C#***.

A good kick-starting tutorial about how xmpp works can he found here: [part one](http://www.adarshr.com/fun-with-xmpp-and-google-talk) and [part two](http://www.adarshr.com/fun-with-xmpp-and-google-talk-part-2).

There is also the [RFC](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-protocols/rfcs/) which contains the most comprehensive documentation out there.